# I cannot open the rear camera with javascript on IOS devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios

My goal is to read a qr code through the website and save it to the database. I do not have problems with Android devices, but I have problems with IOS devices.

I cannot open the rear camera with javascript on IOS devices. Front camera works but rear camera doesn't work. These are also my codes

<!doctype html>

How to use Instascan an HTML5 QR scanner

```
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
            <script src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"></script>
            
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <video id="preview" class="p-1 border" style="width:100%;" playsinline></video>

                <hr>

                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle mb-5" data-toggle="buttons">
              <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" autocomplete="off" checked> Front Camera
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input type="radio" name="options" value="2" autocomplete="off"> Back Camera
              </label>
            </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview'), scanPeriod: 5, mirror: false });
                scanner.addListener('scan',function(content){
                    alert(content);
                    //window.location.href=content;
                });
                Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras){
                    if(cameras.length>0){
                        scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                        $('[name="options"]').on('change',function(){
                            if($(this).val()==1){
                                if(cameras[0]!=""){
                                    scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                                }else{
                                    alert('No Front camera found!');
                                }
                            }else if($(this).val()==2){
                                if(cameras[1]!=""){
                                    scanner.start(cameras[1]);
                                }else{
                                    alert('No Back camera found!');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        console.error('No cameras found.');
                        alert('No cameras found.');
                    }
                }).catch(function(e){
                    console.error(e);
                    alert(e);
                });
            </script>
            
        </div>
        
    
    </div>
</div>
```